# Php nesting code with quotes

Tags: javascript, php, quote

I have some chunks of code I have trouble nesting:

```
return 'autoOpenPopup: '.!empty($options["autoOpenPopup"]) ? $this->int_to_bool($options["autoOpenPopup"]) : $this->int_to_bool(false) . PHP_EOL.'';
```

this prints false (result of autoOpenPopup var) instead of:

```
autoOpenPopup: false
```

It works if I do this:

```
$t = !empty($options["autoOpenPopup"]) ? $this->int_to_bool($options["autoOpenPopup"]) : $this->int_to_bool(false) . PHP_EOL;

return 'autoOpenPopup: '.$t.'';
```

But I wanted to nest this is possible.

Comment: A thing to keep in mind when you code is to make your code understandable and having readability in mind, sometimes it's the better choice to have two lines instead of one.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your ternary code in `(` and `)`?. Like so: `return 'autoOpenPopup: '. (!empty..? .. : .. PHP_EOL.'');`

Comment: Can you explain quickly what `int_to_bool` does? (Does it convert `1` to `true` (string) - and `0` to `false` (string)?

Comment: public function int_to_bool( $value ) {
      return empty($value) ? 'false' : 'true';
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the ternary in parenthesis '(...)';

```
return 'autoOpenPopup: '.( !empty($options["autoOpenPopup"]) ? $this->int_to_bool($options["autoOpenPopup"]) : $this->int_to_bool(false) ) . PHP_EOL.'';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your conditions in a parenthesis and type cast Boolean to String.

```
return 'autoOpenPopup: '.(string) (!empty($options["autoOpenPopup"]) ? $this->int_to_bool($options["autoOpenPopup"]) : $this->int_to_bool(false) . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Why should the op _try this_? What have you changed? Please, explain your answer ;)

Comment: Sure, Thanks @FirstOne